# PHP sql query to order by name and order at the end the category named "x"

Tags: php, mysql, sql

HI i have a query where i make an array to echo al the categories with a parent id (X) pid..

i know how to order them by name the problem is inside every one of them , the is one subcategorie called "others".. this one has to be at the end. so all the "brother" subcategories are ordered alphabetically and the category name "other" goes at the end of that array..

How you do that

```
$sql="select id,name,image from categories where pid=?";
                        $res1=$db->execute_query($sql,array($row['id']));

                        while($row1=$res1->fetch_assoc())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To put the `other` category at the end you can do

```
order by case when cat_name = 'others' then 2 else 1 end asc,
         cat_name asc, 
         name asc
```

Comment: wow can i do that? just one more question how can i add the "ORDER BY name ASC" in that

Answer (score 2):

the other way which only works in mysql,

```
ORDER BY (cat_name = 'others'), cat_name
```

The expression `(cat_name = 'others')` returns 0 for false and 1 for true.

Comment: Wow thanks, but when is false, how do i order it at the bottom, i didnt get that part

Comment: you want `others` to be at the bottom right? so the `ORDER BY` statement will work out. otherwise if you want to reorder `others` to be on top, put `DESC` keywork, eg. `(cat_name = 'others') DESC`.